# Zapier JavaScript and Array

Tags: javascript, zapier

Video Explanation: http://somup.com/cFVT06Vw8l

I am running a Code step that uses regex to find a string in a webhook package and then set my output variables for the next step , zapier email.
The problem is, it only works 1 out of 3-4 times I test. The history shows that the javascript is not working correct...it doesnt error, all green, but its not reliable. What am I missing?

[image: Code on Zapier]

```
var patt1 = new RegExp("test");
var patt2 = new RegExp("teamPlus+");
var patt3 = new RegExp("tier1");
var patt4 = new RegExp("Luli Cleaning");

if(patt1.test(inputData.client)){
    output = {name: 'Pravesh', email: 'y123@gmail.com'};
}
else if(patt2.test(inputData.client))
{
    output = {name: 'teamPlus', email: 't123!@gmail.com'};
}
else if(patt3.test(inputData.client))
{
    output = {name: 'Tier1', email: 'l231@gmail.com'};  
}
else if(patt4.test(inputData.client))
{
    output = {name: 'Luli Cleaning', email: 'lu123@gmail.com'}; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

The issue you're hitting is that your current approach will match if the test string exists anywhere in the input. Your first input:

```
test1234
--
Name 
Phone: (123) 456-7890

[tier1]
```

matches against "test" and returns `Pravesh`.

The main thing you want to do here is make your regex more specific. Especially if you know your tag will always be in `[]` (and that pattern won't show up in the text), you can include that with the test. Either way, you probably don't need regex.

```
if(inputData.client.indexOf('[test]') !== -1){
    output = {name: 'Pravesh', email: 'y123@gmail.com'};
}
else if(inputData.client.indexOf('[teamPlus+]') !== -1)
{
    output = {name: 'teamPlus', email: 't123!@gmail.com'};
}
else if (//...
```

Thanks for including that video, hearing you explain it was helpful. For future reference, troubleshooting is easier on our end if you include an example input that works as you expect and one that doesn't. Also, the array stuff you mentioned in the video isn't relevant here because you're returning an object (noted by the `{}`). ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!